# Why would it display Undefined offset: 0 error for my PHP associative array?

Tags: php, api, exception, associative-array

I am currently using a 3rd party API which returns an associative array. The API has many queries that return data to my website. However If API can't retrieve data that the user has requested it throws a this error , Undefined offset: 0 error and it highlights which line of code the error is coming from which is my associative array

```
$Name = $result[0]['users']['user'][0]['name'];
```

What I am looking to do is create an exception for this occurrence so that it runs a view page e.g.

```
return view('pages.errorPage');
```

NOTE : I am using Laravel.

Comment: Please provide the output of `print_r($Name)`

Comment: Please provide the output of `print_r($result)` not `$name` ... my bad.

Comment: You need to make use of `isset()` to the tune of `if(isset($result[0]['users']['user'][0]['name'])){ /* Do whatever */ }else{ return view('pages.errorPage'); }`

Comment: @Dammeul It will not allow me to print $result as it throws  undefined offset only when the user inputs incorrect data or  a value which the api can't find.

Comment: ahh right... then MonekyZeus is telling you what you need ^^^

Comment: Or Jonathan K below vvv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply place your logic inside a `try` and `catch`.

Example:

```
try {

   // place your logic here

} catch(\Exception $ex) {
   return view('pages.errorPage');
}
```

This would catch any exception thrown

Comment: Please note @John that it's bad practice to not specify the error you're trying to catch in the vast majority of cases

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton I did? In the title and desctiption. Undefined offset: 0 . I'm new to stackoverflow tbh , i could be wrong lol

Comment: @John I'm not talking about your question, I'm talking about the code you ticked, so I thought you might not be aware